# Regarding ColdFusion Mapping

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I am rebuilding my directory structure. The old way had CFC folders in each sub-directory that was a nightmare. I went into ColdFusion administrator and set a mapping (which is actually outside my root). Now here is the confusing part.

My original structure looks similar to this.

```
\appRoot
\appRoot\cfc
\appRoot\modules
\appRoot\modules\cfc
```

I moved the files from the CFC directory inside of modules to the mapped location and all works great. Next I went to move the files from appRoot directory (which is one up from modules) and no matter what I do it will not find those in the mapped directory. It keeps insisting I put the files back in the CFC directory under appRoot.

So why would pages further down the directory structure see the new CFC mappings and not the pages above them?

Comment: Need more info. How are you creating your cfcs? What exactly is the error you’re getting. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Actually I just figured it out this morning. It was the way I was calling it. It need the slash to the path.